# Should it be "text" or "a text" in the following?

Tags: articles

> On the home page, white text/a white text read: *Welcome to Maggie's Blog.*

Should it be *text* or *a text* here? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"a text" is not correct or appropriate here. [Text, in the countable noun sense](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/text_1), means something like "a piece of writing like a book or play; a body of work" A few words on a page isn't really "a text". - Credits to @stangdon

"text" should be correct in this context.

Comment: Sorry, I have to disagree that "**a** text" is correct or appropriate here.  [*Text*, in the countable noun sense](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/text_1), means something like "a piece of writing like a book or play; a body of work."  A few words on a page isn't really "*a* text".

Comment: my bad, my english can be hay-wire sometimes, although its my first language @stangdon

Comment: @alexchenco Note that it could become countable again if we modified the words. Since this is a web page, developers might talk about "a text element." Or anyone might describe it as "a line of text," just as we can turn any non-count noun into a countable thing by specifying an amount ("a cup of flour").